# single word flexibility in exact word search

Tags: mysql, sql

we are implementing a search application

we have implemented a exact word search by the following sql query

```
SELECT *
FROM jreviews_content
WHERE jr_produits REGEXP '[[:<:]]ryan[[:>:]]'
```

Which works well now we would like to tweak it a little
we would like to give the user single word flexibility  at the front or back so that if the user type ryans or ryan or sryan then the system should give the result maintaing the above implemented exact word search .

Comment: are `1234ryan` and `ryan...erwer` valid strings, or just 1 character before/after the word?

Comment: only one letter in front or back

Answer (score 0):

```
set @word='sryan';
SELECT *
FROM (select 'ryan' as a)a
WHERE a like @word
or a like right(@word,length(@word)-1)
or a like left(@word,length(@word)-1)
```

->'ryan'

```
set @word='ryan';
SELECT *
FROM (select 'ryan' as a union all select 'bryan' union all select 'yan' union all select 'yankee')a
WHERE a like @word
or a like right(@word,length(@word)-1)
or a like left(@word,length(@word)-1)
```

-> 'ryan', 'yan'

```
    set @word='ryan';
    SELECT *
    FROM (select 'ryan' as a union all select 'bryan' union all select 'yan' union all select 'yankee')a
where 
a REGEXP concat('[[:<:]]',@word,'[[:>:]]')
or
a REGEXP concat('[[:<:]]',left(@word,length(@word)-1),'[[:>:]]')
or
a REGEXP concat('[[:<:]]',right(@word,length(@word)-1),'[[:>:]]')
```

Comment: can't we do it by tweaking into the regular expression written in above query